# Javafx webengine make loadContent act like synchronous

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, javafx

I want for `loadContent` to finish loading the webpage before I execute the next statement in the method. IE I want it to behave like it is a synchronous method. This is because otherwise I get Javascript exceptions e.g. `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ace` by executing stuff like `webEngine.executeScript(ace ....)`

From a online post, I have tried the following things (but they dont work...

(Try1 )

```
...some code...
this.webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
          return;
        }
    });
    this.webEngine.loadContent(...);
 ...more code...
```

(Try2)

```
...some code...
this.webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
          new CountDownLatch(1).countDown();
        }
    });
    this.webEngine.loadContent(...);
 ...more code...
```

(Try3)

```
...some code...
CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);
this.webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
          latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    this.webEngine.loadContent(...);
 ...more code...
```

PLease help me solve this problem... thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to call `loadContent(...)` on the FX Application Thread. If you then block that thread, it can't render the UI or respond to any user events - this at least potentially includes rendering the web view in which you're loading the content. So this is not the solution you actually want for whatever it is you're trying to do. Probably you simply want to execute whatever code comes next in the handler for the load worker's state property.

Comment: I AM happy to block the thread. please give me solution

Comment: No, you are not happy to block the thread. You won't see *anything* in the UI. (And even if you are, which you're not, posting a solution that did that would not be of any benefit to the general programming community, so would have no place on this site.)